# Script with web3.eth.getAccounts() never ends

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I have a little script just with the following function:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
var web3Provider = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:3001'));
const web3 = new Web3(web3Provider);

web3.eth.getAccounts().then(e => console.log(e));
```

But when I receive the callback, the script is never closed, it continues running (doing nothing). How can I stoped it? why it happens?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike an HTTP connection, a WebSocket needs to be closed explicitly.

You can do it with:

```
web3.currentProvider.connection.close();
```

Or more generally, with:

```
if (web3.currentProvider.constructor.name == "WebsocketProvider")
    web3.currentProvider.connection.close();
```

The latter will allow you to support both types of connection in your script.